# How can i get an audio duration of an mp3 file in React

Tags: reactjs, audio

I tried using some npm packages, but they didn't seem to work, i'm actually using React-audio-player, although the player is playing well and displaying the duration, but i want to be able to get the audio duration before playing and rendering it to my playlist.

```
 <span className="trackTDuration">8:23</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access [audio element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) through `ref` (see [Advanced Usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player)). Audio element provides duration as its member.

Answer (score 3):

When using a component from a library, you can pass the `onLoadedMetadata` props a function where you can get `event`.
And with `event.target.duration`, get the duration you need.

The code will look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';

export const Container = () => {
  const handleLoadMetadata = (meta) => {
    const {duration} = meta.target;
    console.log(duration);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ReactAudioPlayer
        src="path_to_mp3.mp3"
        autoPlay
        controls
        onLoadedMetadata={handleLoadMetadata}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But i can only get the duration of the current song that is play..

Comment: The problem is i have a bunch of audio files that i want to loop through and get their duration in the process.